# Why K8S doesn't wait for the container in the Pod to gracefully shutdown before terminating it?

Tags: kubernetes, npm-start

I have a very simple express app with only one route, receiving requests and I want that when I upgrade the version of the app that K8S will first create another Pod and by the time that the new Pod is ready, that new requests will be point to the new Pod and that the old Pod will remain active until he finishes to serve all the previous requests he received. Only then, and only by the time that I send process.exit(0) from the app, K8S should turn the Pod off.

Why does he turn it off immediately? For example, I have this route:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(`[Preparing...]`)
  setTimeout(() => {
    res.send('Welcome! after delay... NEW 4')
  }, 30000);
})
```

Then I upgrade the version of the app and apply the deployment file again. The request will be aborted in the middle.

Comment: Your process should get SIGTERM, wait 30 seconds, and then SIGKILL, but if your process is taking longer than this to answer a request it could get killed before the response has completed.  See [Termination of Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination) in the Kubernetes documentation.

Comment: But that isn't what happening. The Pod is getting terminated immediately, K8S doesn't wait for process.exit(0) it just kills the pod. I also have configured the setTimeout to be 10s instead of 30s and configured terminationGracePeriodSeconds to 30s but it doesn't help

Comment: Update: the issue is with the CMD ["npm", "start"] in the docker file. Running npm created a process of npm that creates child processes under it. When K8S send SIGTERM it received by the npm process which doesn't bring it down to its childs processes. Using CMD ["node", "index.js"] does the trick since there only one process in the docker container, and it does receive the SIGTERM event. However, I still need to find a way to have npm start that will bring down the event or will leave by the time that its child processes are started.

Comment: Have you looked into dumb-init or tini?

Comment: @SYN I am not sure I understand, can you be more clear?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `node index.js` command? You can also use sleep command in the prestopHook of your deployment to achieve graceful shutdown of your pod https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#hook-details